How to Make PrimeReact Calendar Component Responsive?
I'm using the PrimeReact Calendar component in my project and having trouble making it fully responsive. On smaller screens, it overflows or doesn't adjust properly. How can I ensure it adapts to different screen sizes? Are there specific props or styles I need to apply?
Here’s my current code:
<Calendar value={date} onChange={(e) => setDate(e.value)} showIcon />

Any advice or examples would be appreciated. Thank you!
